# why third level of jqgrid doesn't show?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, hierarchical-data

I use jqgrid in my asp.net mvc project. it has 3 level.
first and second level are shown well but third level doesn't fill and show.
it doesn't go to action in controller.
but if I call that in second level, it works.
I think there is a mistake in fill third level.
here is my code :

```
 function FillJQueryGrid(ProjectIdVal) {

            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCodingCodeSumLists", "Report")' + '?ProjectId=' + ProjectIdVal,
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                    root: function (obj) {
                        return obj.records;
                    }
                },
                datatype: "json",
                height: 'auto',
                page: 1,
                colModel: [
                    { label: 'Fieco Doc No.', name: 'comp_code', key: true },
                    { label: 'Subject', name: 'Comp_Subject' },
                    { label: 'Delay', name: 'sum_delay_count' },

                ],
                loadonce: true,
                height: 'auto',
                autowidth: true,
                rowNum: 20,
                subGrid: true,
                subGridRowExpanded: showChildGridrevision,
                pager: "#jqGridPager"
            });
        };

        //***********************************fill grid level 2 *******************************************
        function showChildGridrevision(parentRowID, parentRowKey) {
            debugger;
            var childGridID = parentRowID + "_table";
            var childGridPagerID = parentRowID + "_pager";

            var childGridURL = '@Url.Action("GetRevisionSumLists", "Report")' + '?CompCode=' + parentRowKey;

            $('#' + parentRowID).append('<table id=' + childGridID + '></table><div id=' + childGridPagerID + ' class=scroll></div>');

            $("#" + childGridID).jqGrid({
                url: childGridURL,
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                    root: function (obj) {

                        return obj.records;
                    }
                },
                datatype: "json",
                height: 'auto',
                page: 1,
                colModel: [
                    { label: 'CompCode_Revision', name: 'CompCode_Revision', key: true, hidden: true },
                    { label: 'comp_code', name: 'comp_code', hidden: true },
                    { label: 'revision', name: 'revision' },
                    { label: 'Delay', name: 'sum_delay_count' }
                ],
                loadonce: true,
                subGrid: true,
                subGridRowExpanded: showChildGridTransmital,
                pager: "#" + childGridPagerID
            });

        }

        //***********************************fill grid level 3 *******************************************
        function showChildGridTransmital(parentRowID, parentRowKey) {
            debugger;
            var childGridID = parentRowID + "_table";
            var childGridPagerID = parentRowID + "_pager";

            var childGridURL = '@Url.Action("GetTransmitalSumLists", "Report")' + '?CompCode_Revision=' + parentRowKey;

            $('#' + parentRowID).append('<table id=' + childGridID + '></table><div id=' + childGridPagerID + ' class=scroll></div>');

            $("#" + childGridID).jqGrid({
                url: childGridURL,
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                    root: function (obj) {

                        return obj.records;
                    }
                },
                datatype: "json",
                height: 'auto',
                page: 1,
                colModel: [
                    { label: 'CompCode_Revision_Transmital', name: 'CompCode_Revision_Transmital', key: true, hidden: true },
                    { label: 'transmital no', name: 'trans_ref_no' },
                    { label: 'transmital subject', name: 'ChkMain_Subject' },
                    { label: 'transmital date', name: 'trans_date' },
                    { label: 'Delay', name: 'sum_delay_count' }
                ],
                loadonce: true,
                subGrid: false,
                pager: "#" + childGridPagerID
            });

        }
```

please help me

Comment: I strictly recommend you to use `idPrefix` which solves possible problem with id dupplicates. For example, `idPrefix: "s_" + parentRowID + "_"`. You should additionally include in all your questions the information about the version of jqGrid, which you use and about the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old/retro version of jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved!
the value of key in level 2,contains comma (',') so the table name of third level contains comma
I replace comma with under line and it works